# Intermittent Freemarker Template Exception, seemingly when under load

Tags: java, freemarker

We've just rolled out some changes to our application and we experienced some Freemarker exceptions intermittently this morning.

Our Freemarker template called `monitoring.ftl` includes `header.ftl` which in turn includes `header_setup.ftl`

In both dev and testing, we have not experienced this exception and since about 9:30 this morning, the exception has not occured in Prod (ie, the template exists and does work for the most part), but before that there was a number of times when the exception below was logged.  And this seemed to be during our peak load time.

So my question is, **has anyone experienced Freemarker intermittently not being able to find a template when under load?**

```
06-Dec-2011 08:10:11 freemarker.log.JDK14LoggerFactory$JDK14Logger error
SEVERE: Template processing error: "Error reading included file WEB-INF/templates/includes/header_setup.ftl"

Error reading included file WEB-INF/templates/includes/header_setup.ftl
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> include "/WEB-INF/templates/includes/header_setup.ftl" [on line 5, column 17 in WEB-INF/templates/includes/header.ftl]
 in include "/WEB-INF/templates/includes/header.ftl" [on line 13, column 5 in WEB-INF/templates/monitoring/monitoring.ftl]
----------

Java backtrace for programmers:
----------
freemarker.template.TemplateException: Error reading included file WEB-INF/templates/includes/header_setup.ftl
        at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:167)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
        at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.include(Environment.java:1508)
        at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:169)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
        at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:199)
        at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)
        at com.gorkana.gdm.jersey.viewprocessors.FreemarkerViewProcessor.writeTo(FreemarkerViewProcessor.java:96)
        at com.gorkana.gdm.jersey.viewprocessors.FreemarkerViewProcessor.writeTo(FreemarkerViewProcessor.java:28)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.template.ResolvedViewable.writeTo(ResolvedViewable.java:103)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter.writeTo(ViewableMessageBodyWriter.java:83)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter.writeTo(ViewableMessageBodyWriter.java:62)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1437)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
        at com.gorkana.gdm.guice.filters.MonitoringSecurityFilter.doFilter(MonitoringSecurityFilter.java:25)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
        at com.gorkana.gdm.guice.filters.PermissionsAndPreferencesFilter.doFilter(PermissionsAndPreferencesFilter.java:27)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
        at com.gorkana.gdm.guice.filters.LoggedInUserRequiredFilter.doFilter(LoggedInUserRequiredFilter.java:30)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.blacksunplc.durrants.dmm.servlets.ExceptionAlerterFilter.doFilter(ExceptionAlerterFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template WEB-INF/templates/includes/header_setup.ftl not found.
        at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:495)

at freemarker.core.Environment.getTemplateForInclusion(Environment.java:1490)
        at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:157)
        ... 83 more
```

Comment: What `cache_storage` and what `TemplateLoader` are you using? What does `${.version}` print? As of the question in bold, I distinctly remember a user had such issue, but I can't find the thread, and anyway AFAIR he was just gone and I couldn't reproduce this myself.

Comment: Not sure about the `cache_storage` mate, but using the standard Freemarker `TemplateLoader`.  Haven't experienced this issue again since I posted this question but it would be nice to find out what the issue was.

Comment: There's no standard `TemplateLoader`. Anyway, if the VM starts to run out of heap space, depending on the cache used, it starts to discard templates from the cache, so they need to be reloaded from the file system when they are next needed. Would that fail, because of some resource shortage (like, even, running out of file handles), I can imagine it ends up like this. Nothing suspicious in the logs around the time of the failure?

Comment: I noticed the class freemarker.cache.TemplateCache synchronizes accesses on some storages and does not on other ones but clear() method is always synchronized. That might be a bug since clear might be designed to be atomical but it might actually run concurrently with other non-synchronized accesses.

Comment: If this is due to a bug in Freemarker, knowing thd precise version of Freemarker will be important.